# Scrollbar position issue with Chrome on mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been looking everywhere and tried almost everything I could to fix this issue but no chance.

The website I'm working on works as expected on desktop view, however the mobile view is a different story...

Safari is OK but Chrome on iPhone has some weird behavior when I trigger a pull-to-refresh or overscroll. I cannot resolve it myself and hope the community can help!

Here the last version of my CSS code:

```css
/* put styles header */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
    
#container {
    min-height: 100vh; /* will cover the 100% of viewport */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* height of your footer */
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

[image: View of the scrollbar at the first load]

[image: After over scrolling or pull-to-refresh]

I tried to hide it, reset the scrollbar position or disable overscroll/pull-to-refresh

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your HTML.

In HTML file inside head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can explore more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks for your comment the other day. I had this in my meta already so I thought it wasn’t related but it is! My meta settings was not applied correctly and not reflected in the header of the index file after building. I fixed this part and now it works as expected. I cannot mark it as the right answer, that would be great if someone could do it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see such a bug with google.com, with stackoverflow.com and many other sites.
I guess it is not your problem, but google chrome’s under iOS

Comment: Hey Paul. If you want to contribute to the conversation, but don't really have an answer for the person posting a question, it's best to not create an answer with your comment, but comment on the question directly. Thanks!